# Load groups of csv files in MYSQL and preserve the relationships even when the ids start equally on each group

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have several groups of CSV files that I need to take into a mysql database. The CSVs are as follows:

Products (it has a product_id)
ShippingDetails (related to products csv file through product_id)
Categories (related to products csv file through product_id)

I have 3 groups of these files

Group1: Products1.csv, ShippingDetails1.csv, Categories1.csv
Products2.csv, ShippingDetail2.csv, ...
...

The files on each group are realted with product_id.

The problem is that I want to load all the group of files in a database, but the id for product_id starts from 0 on each group. So I need a way to change the id so that it becomes unique for all products, no matter from what csv file it comes. Also, I would need to change the relationships (foreign keys) on each group to make them match with the new unique id when all data is taken to a single table. In the real scenario I have a bunch of tables that are all related with the product_id on each group. So I was wondering if MySQL can fix the relationships on the go, or what's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if MySQL can do that for you, but it can be done with a simple script. For example in PHP, assuming you have the tables products and shipping_details empty in your database:

```
$group_count = 3;

mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

for ($max_product_id = 0, $group = 1; $group <= $group_count; $group++)
{
    // create temporary tables
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE products_tmp LIKE products");
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE shipping_details_tmp LIKE shipping_details");

    // load data from csv files
    mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'Products$group.csv' INTO TABLE products_tmp");
    mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'ShippingDetails$group.csv' INTO TABLE shipping_details_tmp");

    // update unique ids
    mysql_query("UPDATE products_tmp SET product_id = product_id + $max_product_id");
    mysql_query("UPDATE shipping_details_tmp SET product_id = product_id + $max_product_id");

    // insert into final tables
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO products SELECT * FROM products_tmp");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO shipping_details SELECT * FROM shipping_details_tmp");

    // drop temporary tables
    mysql_query("DROP TABLE products_tmp");
    mysql_query("DROP TABLE shipping_details_tmp");

    // get max product_id to update next group of data
    list($max_product_id) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(product_id)+1 FROM products"));
}
```

The logic of this code is to insert the first group of data into the tables, get the max product_id + 1, and before inserting the next group of data you add that number to every product_id. That way product_id will always be unique and relationships will be kept. In the example code I just used 2 tables but you can extend this to how many tables you need.

**Notes:**

- When loading data from csv files (with LOAD DATA INFILE...) you should give an absolute path to the file. I didn't do that to keep the code cleaner.
- I used old mysql functions because it's simple to write, but for production code it's better to use something like PDO.